# Google maps iOS sdk crashing with 'libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain:' crash after 1 minute

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added google maps sdk (v 2.2) through pods to my project .when I initialized GMSMapview with frame and camera it is showing location fine, but after some time it is crashing with following crash even i'm not doing any functionality with map. I added GMSMapview programatically instead of through story board. I've attached screen shot of crash as well.Any one faced this issue help me out please.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlZHa.png

Comment: For `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, this is nowhere near enough information for us to help you. You need to at least **show us your code**, as well as **show us code that works without a crash**. In general, EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you were holding a reference to something in a variable, then accessing it, which isn't there anymore.

Comment: camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[self.geoFenchModel.lattitude doubleValue]
                                                 longitude:[self.geoFenchModel.longitude doubleValue]
                                                      zoom:self.geoFenchModel.zoomLevel];googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:mapFrame camera:camera];
        googleMapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
        [self.mapBackgroundView addSubview:googleMapView];

Comment: Hi xaphod. This is what the code I've written for showing location on GMSMapview. Here  geofencemodel is model object to save user location. It's showing the location fine, but after 1 min it's crashing.

Comment: @manideep hi! did you find a solution for this?